# Parsing Autosar xml using beautiful soup python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse AUTOSAR specific arxml (similar to xml file) using Python but I am unable to read the contents of the file. I want to get the `DEFINITION-REF` values of definitions inside multiple `ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE` tags eg:

```
/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef
```

I tried multiple ways but I am unable to print out the contents.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def parseArxml():
    handler = open('input.arxml').read()
    soup = Soup(handler,"html.parser")
    for ecuc_container in soup.findAll('ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE'):
        print(ecuc_container)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseArxml()
```

Here is a part of the arxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 autosar_4-2-1.xsd">
      <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE UUID="c112c504-e546-41c3-abf9-0aaf06b18284">
      <SHORT-NAME>BswMLogicalExpression_2</SHORT-NAME>
      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression</DEFINITION-REF>
      <REFERENCE-VALUES>
        <ECUC-REFERENCE-VALUE>
          <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-CHOICE-REFERENCE-DEF">/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef</DEFINITION-REF>
          <VALUE-REF DEST="ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE">/ARRoot/BswM_0/BswMConfig_0/BswMArbitration_0/BswMModeCondition_2</VALUE-REF>
        </ECUC-REFERENCE-VALUE>
      </REFERENCE-VALUES>
    </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>

    <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE UUID="c112c504-e546-41c3-abf9-0aaf06b18284">
      <SHORT-NAME>BswMLogicalExpression_3</SHORT-NAME>
      <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression</DEFINITION-REF>
      <REFERENCE-VALUES>
        <ECUC-REFERENCE-VALUE>
          <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-CHOICE-REFERENCE-DEF">/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef</DEFINITION-REF>
          <VALUE-REF DEST="ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE">/ARRoot/BswM_2/BswMConfig_2/BswMArbitration_2/BswMModeCondition_3</VALUE-REF>
        </ECUC-REFERENCE-VALUE>
      </REFERENCE-VALUES>
    </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
</AUTOSAR>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see with `print(soup)` that tag names were converted to lower-case by the parser. So use lowercase when searching for tag names:

```
for ecuc_container in soup.findAll('ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE'.lower()):
```

or simply:

```
for ecuc_container in soup.findAll('ecuc-container-value'):
```

Or even better: explicitly parse the document as XML, so that the case of tags is not modified:

```
soup = Soup(handler,'xml')
```

Here's how you can get a list of the text inside `<DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">` elements:

```
def parseArxml():
    handler = open('input.arxml').read()
    soup = Soup(handler,'xml')
    dest = [d.text for d in soup.findAll('DEFINITION-REF') if d['DEST']=='ECUC-CHOICE-REFERENCE-DEF']   
    print(dest)
```

Output:

```
['/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef',
'/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef']
```

Or if you want to get all `definition-ref` tags regardless of attribute, use

```
dest = [d.text for d in soup.findAll('definition-ref')]
```

Comment: thanks. I even went ahead and tried using "lxml-xml" parser for beautiful soup and the case for the tags was not modified. (the case doesn't matter much). can u please suggest me which will be the best parser to use for more complex XML files?

Comment: I suggest using `soup = Soup(handler,'xml')` to explicitly parse the document as XML. This will conserve the uppercase. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers

Comment: Also consider using a pure XML parser like ElementTree or LXML directly instead of using BeautifulSoup if the XML is well-formed.  It will be faster.

Comment: ElementTree works perfectly, traversing through the xml is like a tree. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your parser and BeautifulSoup version is converting tags to lowercase.

You should do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

def parseArxml():
    handler = open('input.arxml').read()
    soup = Soup(handler,"html.parser")
    for ecuc_container in soup.find_all('ecuc-container-value'):
        for def_ref in ecuc_container.find_all('definition-ref'):
            print(def_ref.get_text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseArxml()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression
/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef
/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression
/AUTOSAR/ecucdef/BswM/BswMConfig/BswMArbitration/BswMLogicalExpression/BswMArgumentRef
```